# Why do the qasm_simulator runtimes vary significantly for different IBMQ CouplingMap/NoiseModels?

Tags: qiskit, programming, vqe

I have been running VQE experiments locally using the `qasm_simulator` with actual IBMQBackend NoiseModels as shown in the [Qiskit Textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html#Running-VQE-on-a-Noisy-Simulator). I have noticed that the simulation runtimes for certain backends(e.g. `ibmq_vigo` - 5 qubits/`ibmq_rome` - 5 qubits) are significantly faster than others which in fact seem to run indefinitely and do not finish executing(e.g. `ibmq_manhattan` - 65 qubits/`ibmq_montreal` - 27 qubits).

Noting that I am running the same VQE experiments on all 4 `NoiseModel`s I do not understand why this extreme simulation runtime variation exists.

How is this explained? and if not immediately resolvable would using the NoiseModel for `ibmq_vigo` in tandem with the coupling map of say `ibmq_manhattan` in the case that the desired VQE variational form exceeds 5 qubits(i.e. the number of qubit on `ibmq_vigo`) - e.g. VQE on $BeH_2$ - result in faster execution?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the qubits are not neighbors and the circuit require a lot of intermediate qubits to execute certain operations. This could means that you are trying to simulate a very large problem. I would suggest that you transpiled the circuit onto those device qubit's layout and see what the circuit might looks like.

---

On the side note, by looking at the code from the linked you provided, I see this:

```
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q')
backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")
device = provider.get_backend("ibmq_vigo")
coupling_map = device.configuration().coupling_map
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(device.properties())
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend=backend, 
                                   shots=1000, 
                                   noise_model=noise_model, 
                                   coupling_map=coupling_map,
                                   measurement_error_mitigation_cls=CompleteMeasFitter,
                                   cals_matrix_refresh_period=30)
```

I just want to point out that by performing `measurement_error_mitigation` with CompleteMeasFitter can be costly and could slow down your simulation if you are using a lot of qubits. This is because Qiskit is trying to calibrated a $2^n \times 2^n$ ($n$ is the number of qubit you are using) matrix to mitigate the measurement error.

For the case of Manhattan, assuming that you are using all of the qubit then this is $2^{65} \times 2^{65}$ matrix! It would takes years (maybe?).

As for why do we need to we need to create $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix, this is because you are creating $2^n$ eigenstate and measure each of them. Says you have $3$-qubit, and you want to understand how much error is happening in your measurement, what you do is then to prepare the $2^3$ eigenstates:

$$|000\rangle, |001\rangle, \cdots, |111\rangle $$

and make measurement on them. Measuring the first eigenstate will give you some probability distribution  like:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0.80\\
0.02\\
0.04\\
0.01\\
0.03\\
0.05\\
0.04\\
0.01\\
\end{pmatrix} \hspace{1 cm} $$
You do this for the other 7 eigenstates, and hence you formed an $2^3 \times 2^3$ matrix, says $M$. Then by operate $M^{-1}$ to the probability vector you generated by measuring some state $|\psi \rangle$, you will be able to recover (to some extent) the result that doesn't have the read out error.

As you can see, this is a very expensive process. And that is why your simulation is taking forever.